# Debounced function calls delayed but all executed when wait timer ends

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

I am using [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#debounce) in order to implement a 'search as you type' field.

I am reading https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ and from what I can understand the function should only be called a limited number of times.

In my case, the function calls are delayed, but executed all at once once the wait timer ends:

```
methods: {
  searchOnType: function (currentPage, searchString) {
    console.log(`Searching ${searchString}`)
    var debounced = throttle(this.getMovies, 4000, {leading: false, trailing: true})
    debounced('movies.json', currentPage, searchString)
  },
  getMovies: function (url, page, query) {
    console.log(query)
    this.loading = true
    resourceService.getMovies(url, page, query).then((result) => {
      this.items = result.movies
      this.totalMovies = result.total
      this.loading = false
    })
  },
```

the HTML (it's Vue.JS)

```
  <input 
    type="text" 
    v-model="searchString" 
    class="form-control input-lg" 
    placeholder="search movie" 
    @keydown="searchOnType(currentPage, searchString)"
  >
```

This is my console.log:[image: console]

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a throttled function every time you `keydown` (you should probably be using `input` instead by the way). You can do this instead I think...

```
methods: {
  searchOnType: throttle((currentPage, searchString) => {
    this.getMovies('movies.json', currentPage, searchString)
  }, 1000, {leading: false, trailing: true})
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, I just read it in the docs http://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed .. thanks ! but your syntax is a bit wrong, can you check the doc and rectify so I can √ ?

Comment: The syntax is fine though. It all depends how you want to handle it. I'll updated my example to handle the arguments.

Comment: So what was happening with what I was doing before?

Comment: You were creating a bunch of different `debounced` functions.